# ReactJS: modify value of dynamic key value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I have a react form with a list of "subform" as react component. I want to update the "global" form value from those child component.

One of my child component looks like that :

```js
function ForecastForADay(props: any) {
  const { formValue, setFormValue } = useContext(FormContext)
  return (
    <>
      ...
       <input
          type="number"
          placeholder="0"
          className="form-control w-10"
          onChange={(x) =>
            setFormValue((oldVal: Forecasts) => {
              var nVal = oldVal
              ;(nVal[props.objField as keyof Forecasts] as SingleForecast).temperatureMin = parseInt(x.target.value)
              return nVal
            })
          }
        ></input>
      ...
    </>
  )
}
```

As you can see I use a context for the whole form value (cause there's multiple layers of component). My issue is that in the `onChange` function, it modify all the fields of the nVal object instead of only modifying `porps.objField`.

`props.objField` as the correct value which corespond to a field's name.

Do you have any idea why this behaviour occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are experiencing is related to object mutability in JavaScript. When you write `var nVal = oldVal`, you are creating a reference to the same object that is stored in `oldVal`. Therefore, any changes made to nVal will also affect `oldVal`. In other words, both `oldVal` and `nVal` are pointing to the same object in memory.

To avoid this issue, you should create a copy of the object before modifying it. One way to achieve this is by using the spread operator (...) to create a shallow copy of the object.

Change `setFormValue` as:

```
setFormValue((oldVal: Forecasts) => {
  const nVal = { ...oldVal }; // Create a shallow copy of the object
  nVal[props.objField as keyof Forecasts] = {
    ...nVal[props.objField as keyof Forecasts], // Create a shallow copy of the nested object
    temperatureMin: parseInt(x.target.value)
  };
  return nVal;
});
```